# Integrate Biometric for existing application

Tags: android-studio, android-biometric

I’m a beginner engineer, all I want to know is how we can integrate biometric authentication to existing projects. I’m aware of the biometric authentication process and tried as an example and it worked out . Please show me a way to find this one. I’ve searched many websites related to this, but couldn’t find anything. I’m supposed to know how we can start with biometric login without prompting a biometric icon or something that is I need to login whenever I touch the sensor while the app is opening. And then after successfully login, how can we be redirected to the home page using the URL in android studio. Your time and efforts will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What language you're programming on?

Comment: in Java language

Comment: Sorry to say, I'm not familiar with the language.